# Rally APIKEY with single sign using Pyral

Tags: rally, pyral

Using Rally APIKEY in a single sign on environment with a proxy  throws error that it can not reach rally1.rallydev.com-

Tried setting HTTPS_PROXY As well, No result.

I can reach from browser and it auto signs me up via single signon.

Did anyone try apikey authorization in single sign on proxy environment using pyral, if so can u please share how u did it?—-thank you

Comment: Please paste the error message

Comment: Tried requests.post( url, data, headers)

Comment: where url = rally1.rallydev.com, data is my jsdon.dump(query)

Comment: headers has zesession set with api key.   I get error '11004, get addrinfo failed.   Erroneous error.  I can reach rally1.rallydev.com using  browser and I can also fire rest api calls using browser.   may be my proxy not sending the headers. not sure what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Having as similar issue:
rally = Rally(server=server, apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)
pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: SSL certificate verification failed

my organization is not ready to give the proxy server details any other work around for the issue.

sorry was not able to add a comment so posting as answer.